# Windows Phone P2P TCP/IP Connection

Tags: sockets, windows-phone-8, tcp

I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 app (game). In the app, I need to be able to start a TCP/IP connection with another phone (lobby match-up), and then send messages to and from, without a centralized server. I am currently following [this](http://www.codeguru.com/win_mobile/phone_apps/building-tcpip-applications-on-the-windows-phone-platform.htm) tutorial, however, I need connect to another Windows Phone, not a server. Is this possible without a centralized server? If so, how might I go about doing it? If not, would I be better off using PeerFinder or some other P2P type connection finder? 
Alternatively, could I find another phone using PeerFinder and set up a socket connection there?

I guess in essence, my question is: what are the alternatives/what are my options if I want to connect to another Windows Phone, but without a central server?

Answer (score 2):

First of all sorry about my English.

Most probably you can use wifi for the work.its not good enough to make a program that is always listening to a port. Because it makes a security hall. So it is better to open the TCP port only when you need it also make it to manual as much as possible.

To connect two phones together you can follow the following procedure.

*First of all you need to specify a conmen TCP port for the all users*

**INITIAL HANDSHAKING**

- Make sure that relevant application is running on both mobile phones.
- Make the application to auto on wifi when it's initiating it self.
- Make a button call "Search for users".
- when user click it open a specific TCP port which is unique for the application.
- then search for the open wifi connections.
- send a TCP packet for the selected port which you set for the application and wait for the acknowledgement.
- List all the connections who sent the acknowledgement (Available application users).

**SELECT A USER**

- Enable user to select one of the user from available list
- Then send a TCP request to selected user.
- Receiver can accept or reject it
- by accepting it user make his/her TCP end point to IP that sends data.
- Then you can simply transfer the data via opened port.

its better if you can allocate list of TCP ports to use. then you can write an algorithm to select another when one is allocated by another program.

I think this will be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. While this wasn't exactly what I was looking for, this is a different (and clever) way of connecting over TCP/IP. I will probably keep this as a backup strategy.